# Unknown networks, is Malware?

Tags: network, catalina, malware, virus

I got a Mac with Catalina 10.15.6

When I access Network (*Rede* in image) in Finder, it show me a strange network, if I disconnect WiFi and connect again its show me a another network name...

<del>Until then it only showed me not more one in same time.</del>
I've seen 2 networks at the same time:

- _dns-llq._udp.identrust.com
- isrg.trustid.ocsp.identrust.com

[image]

Example of network names that appear:

- isrg.trustid.ocsp.identrust.com
- fzlecimhhcab
- ltrkufb
- gswjiugohfxkahw
- xctjqgqhakhx
- jjtizuktaatwpc
- ckxyfhmtddi
- _dns-llq._udp.identrust.com
- vrqacxveocpcgaj
- xzgdecneswqfi
- zggsetbbq
- peepwxbqlb
- zveumgjmzy
- local.avg.com
- lehoafria

and anothers names...

I stay in same Network Wifi Internet.

What is this?

Comment: Turn off everything in system preferences > sharing. whose network is this ? work, personal etc ?

Comment: All of things In sharing are in off, the network is personal.

Comment: This may depend on the network you are connecting to. It is *possible* that whoever is supplying you with WiFi/internet has people set up in one big shared network of networks and has failed to hide the other networks. The names being (seemingly) random characters may be some automated network device that is not doing well. I might be tempted to contact the people who supply your WiFi/Internet and see if they can tell you what is going on

Comment: @SteveChambers this is not the case, the network to which the machine is connected is closed. But it could be that if the network were public and open.

Comment: I hope you are right. the fact that you see other *networks* in the network browser is concerning from an InfoSec standpoint. And I am not aware of anything specific to macOS that would enable this kind of thing. Unless someone here has a specific idea I would consider seeing if the mods think this would be appropriate for https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/